# Auto-property with initializer referencing instance member

Tags: c#, properties, initializer, c#-6.0

This is working code

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand CommandA { get; }
    public DelegateCommand CommandB { get; }

    public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }        

    // stupid constructor
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        CommandA = new DelegateCommand(OnCommandA);
        CommandB = new DelegateCommand(o => SomeProperty = true;);
    }
    void OnCommandA(object obj) { ... }
}
```

And this one is not

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand CommandA { get; } = new DelegateCommand(OnCommandA); // error
    public DelegateCommand CommandB { get; } = new DelegateCommand(o => SomeProperty = true;); // error

    public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }        

    void OnCommandA(object obj) { ... }
}
```

Error is

> Error CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

My question is: why? Why should something be `static`? This is supposed to be a cool feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing new here, really. Forget automatically implemented properties - you simply can't refer to `this` within a field initializer.  (Let's face it, you're trying to initialize a field under the hood - just a field which is only exposed via a property.)

So this has always been invalid:

```
class Foo
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = x; // Nope, compile-time error
    int z = DoSomething(); // Nope...

    int DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

Generally, this avoids:

- Reliance on initialization order, which can lead to brittle code
- Calling methods before the base class initializer has executed

I agree that for method group conversions it's a *bit* of an unnecessary pain - but the language is simpler with just one rule.

As you've seen, you can easily put the code in the constructor - so I'd just go with that. (And hey, at least we do now *have* read-only automatically-implemented properties that can be initialized from constructors...)

It's important to understand that the compiler error message isn't really telling you that anything *should* be static - it's just telling you what you can't do. The solution depends on your situation - and in this case, the right solution is almost certainly to put the initialization in a constructor.

Comment: Jon, if both members are static this is allowed. Obviously that also rely on order of initialization but why it is allowed? (I'm trying to find answer for this for a long time)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Well, things are at least a *bit* simpler in that case because there's no inheritance involved. I think it's mostly because the trade-off between safety and inconvenience is different - it would be really inconvenient to always have to write a static constructor for that case, but for instances you've often got a constructor anyway *and* you're less likely to initialize one field based on another.